# element.prevUntil("option:contains()") not returning expected result

Tags: jquery

Let's say that I have no control over the format of the HTML, which is:

```
<select id="foods">
  <option value='0'>Some Vegetables</option>
  <option value='1'>-Carrot</option>
  <option value='2'>Some Fruits</option>
  <option value='3'>-Apple</option>
  <option value='4'>-Orange</option>
  <option value='5' selected='selected'>-Strawberry</option>
<select>
```

I am trying to get the "parent" option of Strawberry, which would be 'Some Fruits'. I'd assume that I could do that with:

```
var strawberry = $('#foods).find(':selected')
// This gives me strawberry.text() = '-Strawberry', as expected
var parentVal = strawberry.prevUntil("option:not(:contains('-'))").val()
```

However, this returns `parentVal = 4`, corresponding with -Orange.

```
var parentVal = strawberry.prevUntil("option:contains('-')").val()
```

...gives me `parentText = undefined`

```
var parentVal = strawberry.prevUntil("option:contains('Fruits')").val()
```

...gives me `parentVal = 4`, corresponding with -Orange.

```
var parentVal = strawberry.prevUntil("option:contains('Fruits'))").prev().val()
```

...gives me `parentVal = 3`, corresponding with -Apple.

What's going on? Obviously I'm misunderstanding how `.prevUntil()` works, or at least how it works in the context of `<option>` elements. Any input on what's going on and how I can return 'Some Fruits' when any of the fruits are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prevAll()` insted of `.prevUntil()`

```
var parentVal = strawberry.prevAll("option:contains('Fruits')").val()
```

**Demo**

```js
var strawberry = $('#foods').find(':selected')
var parentVal = strawberry.prevAll("option:contains('Fruits')").val()

console.log(parentVal)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foods">
  <option value='0'>Some Vegetables</option>
  <option value='1'>-Carrot</option>
  <option value='2'>Some Fruits</option>
  <option value='3'>-Apple</option>
  <option value='4'>-Orange</option>
  <option value='5' selected='selected'>-Strawberry</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Man, just using the wrong function this whole time. Could you explain why `.prevAll()` works but `prevUntil()` doesn't? I guess I just have a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it explains it better than i can http://www.moreonfew.com/difference-between-prev-prevall-prevuntil-jquery-api/

Comment: Thank you! Any related questions I found on here used `.prevUntil()` and the descriptions in the jQuery documentation weren't too clear. That article cleared it all up.